Pass list to stored procedure using Dapper
My model looks like this
public class Model
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public List<AnotherModel> Sample{ get; set; }
}
public class AnotherModel
{
    public int RequestID { get; set; }

    public int RequestName { get; set; }
}

I'm calling stored procedure and passing this object as follows.
 var result = await _Connection.QueryFirstOrDefaultAsync<ResponseModel>($@"EXEC GetRequestData @ID=@ID,@Names= @Sample", new
 {
     Model.ID,Model.Sample
 });

Stored procedure
DECLARE @ID int ,@Names varchar(MAX)
DECLARE @Table TABLE (RequestID int, RequestName int)      

INSERT INTO @Request_Table
SELECT RequestID , RequestName FROM OPENJSON(@Names ) 
     WITH (TempDataset nvarchar(max) as json) A
     OUTER APPLY OPENJSON(A.TempDataset ) 
     WITH (RequestID int '$.RequestID',
           RequestName int '$.RequestName')
...........Query tables along with Table created above

This throws an exception
The member of type ....Models.AnotherModel cannot be used as a parameter value
I'm trying to pass list of values to the procedure. What am i missing here? Any alternate solution will also work if possible.
Tried passing list of object to stored procedure which is failing
